# Is it acceptable as a professional developer not to write unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, automated-tests

Just wondering on the pros and cons on TDD/automated unit testing and looking for the community's view on whether it's acceptable for professional developers to write applications without supporting unit tests?

Re-asked on Programmers: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159572/is-it-acceptable-as-a-professional-developer-not-to-write-unit-tests

Comment: If you you don't test your stuff, how do you know it is correct. Doesn't seem professional to me.

Answer (score 2):

I bet I'll get -1 -ed for this, but I still say: *if you have other measures to ensure quality, including avoiding regression, program validation, program verification, then* **no.**

The only problem is usually that people don't have any other tools than unit testing to achieve this.

In case you have formally tested models (there's a tool, that actually tests it, or it was constructed in a way which ensures it's valid), and you have formally tested ways to ensure that the actually running software is conform to that model, then it's fine.

Example: if you are sure, that the code you wrote in ruby will act as you'd expect it (because you or someone else tested the ruby interpreter and it doesn't have bugs, or you use only a subset of features known to be safe) then its fine. Usually, we trust C compilers and CPUs in this manner.

Also, if a program is only to be used once,there's no regression problem! If I write a one-liner in bash, which will calculate something for me, I might test it first manually on fake data, then run it on the real one - no need to write an automated test.

If you take the blame, you can also go with along with assumptions: I assume usually, that eclipse is pretty good at creating setters and getters, and I don't test on those. Also, I assume, that in case there'd be any problem with java's Collection classes in Java 7, it'd have turned out by now. But in case there's a trouble, it's your personal trouble. Don't blame anyone.

Personally, I rarely use unit testing on certain codes as I formally test them while they're still flowcharts on a piece of paper, and I ensure that I only use subsets of the language/libraries which are known to work in such situations. Also, I never let code out without peer review. Still, it's sometimes better if there's someone who runs an acceptance test on them...

Comment: Nobody said you should rely on unit tests *alone*. That would be silly - just as silly as relying on formal proof or manual testing only.

Answer (score 1):

It is up to you. The question is more philosophical in nature.

Unit tests are just a tool to help you. You can chose to ignore them. However, if you are going to work on a more than trivial project I would advise you to use unit tests.

Yes, they take time, too to write. But in the end you will save a lot if there is any refactoring done or some parts of the code need to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As always: It depends.

Generally speaking, unit tests are a good thing: they catch a whole class of errors, they verify that particular parts of your code work as expected under given circumstances, and they make it easier to track down errors when something does go wrong. So unless you have good reasons not to, you should write unit tests.

Good reasons not to write unit tests include:

- Making relatively small changes to a codebase that is structured badly and hardly testable because of this (usually, the reason is that there is little separation of concerns, and testable units cannot be isolated for testing without intrusive changes to the codebase itself).
- The nature of the problem domain makes the code inherently untestable. This is rare, but it happens - for example, it is very hard to come up with meaningful unit tests for a routine that draws a GUI: you'd have to make it render to a mocked surface and then check individual pixels, but you'd also have to mock all the parameters that influence layout decisions, etc.; while this is theoretically possible, it's not usually worth the effort, and one should opt for manual or semi-automatic testing in such cases.
- The project is a tiny throwaway program with such a small scope and such a short lifecycle that the benefit gained from unit testing (increased maintainability, decreased complexity) is marginal. Keep in mind, however, that software tends to live longer than it was designed for, and your one-off throwaway script might very well end up becoming a mission-critical part of the company's processes.

Comment: Sometimes I wish I would have statistics from maniac TDD guys on actually how many times did tests fail to them unexpectedly (before implementation doesn't count), and how complex those bugs were. My personal experience, that if I'm not writing a difficult, domain-driven business logic, tests show nothing, and you can write thousands of lines and then refactor them without finding out about a single bug through them. (Pls note: I usually don't have bugs, at least as long as I followed my projects)

Comment: @Aadaam:I'm certainly not a TDD maniac, but automated tests have saved me on several occasions, especially with dynamic languages without a compiler that yells at you for doing stupid things or making silly typos. Also, finding bugs is just *one* of the reasons you write unit tests - formally defining and documenting the unit's behavior (in TDD, even before implementing it), building a collection of regression tests, and organizing your thoughts in a retracable manner are others. You can even use them to actively trace places that need attention while refactoring, which is tremendously useful.

Comment: for organizing my thoughts, and documenting before implementation, I have UML, it easily can be that I'm their last user for this, but it served me well for over a decade. I tried these solely TDD/BDD methods (I had to), but I always found them cumbersome and not as effective as drawing a series of models and checking if everything is fine with them. That said, when it comes to OCL-like stuff, unit tests are the way to go of course.